# Eigenvalue bounds on $2\times 2$ block matrix with diagonal off-diagonals

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

Let $A,D\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with eigenvalues $\alpha_i,\delta_i$ and let $b,c\in\mathbb{C}$. Without loss of generality, I've been able to prove the following statements.

- The eigenvalues of $K =\begin{bmatrix}A & bI\\ cI & A\end{bmatrix}$ are given by $\kappa_i=\alpha_i\pm\sqrt{bc}$.
- The eigenvalues of $L=\begin{bmatrix}A & bI\\ cI & 0\end{bmatrix}$ are given by $\lambda_i=\frac{\alpha_i}{2}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{\alpha_i}{2}\right)^2+bc}$.

Given these facts, I would like to find a bound (or closed form) for the eigenvalues $\mu_i$ of $M=\begin{bmatrix}A & bI\\ cI & D\end{bmatrix}$.

Numerically, I've observed that all $\mu_i$ lie within the convex hull of all $\alpha_i\pm\sqrt{bc}$ and all $\delta_i\pm\sqrt{bc}$. However, I'm struggling to prove this mathematically. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: @Shaun there are no set products in my question

Comment: What about "$2\times 2$"? The title . . .

Comment: @Shaun My bad! Also added some context.